# Sqlite compare value between rows

Tags: sqlite

I have a table BOOKDOCUMENT with some fields (Id, documentDate);

documentDate has this format : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS".

I would like to get the average value in days between each documentDate of my table.

So my idea is to compage each documentDate.

Exemple : the last row with the row - 1 = it give my first value
the last row - 1 with the last row -2 = it give my second value

```
SELECT julianday(DocumentDate) -
   (
     SELECT julianday(DocumentDate)
     FROM BOOKDOCUMENT
     WHERE Id = 25
   ) AS daysBetweenDoc
FROM BOOKDOCUMENT
WHERE Id = 26
UNION ALL
SELECT julianday(DocumentDate) -
       (
         SELECT julianday(DocumentDate)
         FROM BOOKDOCUMENT
         WHERE Id = 24
       ) AS daysBetweenDoc

FROM BOOKDOCUMENT
WHERE Id = 25;
```

It's working find BUT how can I can value for other rows ? 
I think I have to use CTE

Comment: Are the ID values guaranteed to be continuous?

Comment: Hello, no unfortunately. So anayway, I think I can't use  CTE  to increment ID values...

Comment: Please make an [mcve] and provide the desired output for a few examples which are contained in the MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the next smaller date with a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
SELECT Id,
       DocumentDate,
       julianday(DocumentDate) -
       (SELECT DocumentDate
        FROM BookDocument AS T2
        WHERE T2.DocumentDate < BookDocument.DocumentDate
        ORDER BY DocumentDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS daysBetweenDoc
FROM BookDocument;
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. 
I didn't know about correlated subquery.
Thank you.